# How to write a string from XML to variable in React Native?

Tags: react-native, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have a XML file. I need to import it with URL, beacuse it updates every day. I don't understand how to import it and use information from it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a small example for you

first import library

`var XMLParser = require('react-xml-parser');`

```
fetch()
.then(response => response.text())
.then(xmlText => (new XMLParser().parseFromString(xmlText)))
.then(data => console.log(data.getElementsByTagName('Name')))//or any other tag
```